# HTML range slider with details

Tags: javascript, html

I just wanna know if there is a way to use html range slider as a slider that can dynamically view words and not numbers? Somewhat like this

[image]

Comment: This might be useful : https://codepen.io/trevanhetzel/pen/rOVrGK

Comment: Thanks @NikhileshKV. I'll check on this.

Answer (score 0):

original HTML element slider cannot display text on it, but you can wrap a component combine text and slider, watch the value change and update the text by yourself.